# Basics of D3's Force-directed Layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, physics-engine

I'm plowing into the exciting world of force-directed layouts with d3.js. I've got a grasp of the fundamentals of d3, but I can't figure out the basic system for setting up a force-directed layout.

Right now, I'm trying to create a simple layout with a few unconnected bubbles that float to the center. Pretty simple right!? The circles with the correct are created, but nothing happens.

**Edit: the problem seems to be that the force.nodes() returns the initial data array. On working scripts, force.nodes() returns an array of objects.**

Here's my code:

```
<script>
  $(function(){

    var width = 600,
        height = 400;

    var data = [2,5,7,3,4,6,3,6];


    //create chart
    var chart = d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .attr('class','chart')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

    //create force layout
    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .gravity(30)
        .alpha(.2)
        .size([width, height])
        .nodes(data)
        .links([])
        .charge(30)
        .start();

    //create visuals
    var circles = chart.selectAll('.circle')
        .data(force.nodes()) //what should I put here???
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('class','circles')
        .attr('r', function(d) { return d; });

    //update locations
    force.on("tick", function(e) {
      circles.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    });

  });


</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here was the problem. The array you feed into `force.nodes(array)` needs to be an array of objects.

So:

`var data = [{number:1, value:20}, {number:2, value:30}...];`

works. Or even just

`var data=[{value:1},{value:2}];`

makes the script work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `cx` and `cy` in `force.on` handler.

```
//update locations
force.on("tick", function(e) {

  circles.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x - deltaX(d, e) ; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y - deltaY(d, e); });
});
```

And functions `deltaX` and `deltaY` depends on your force model.

Comment: I thought the force-layout was providing the updated locations of d.x and d.y. Where is deltaX() coming from? I'm trying to look through working examples, and the examples are always just updating with return d.x